# WebRTC release video input but have audio stream running

Tags: webrtc

I have a stream with audio and video, just as [apprtc](https://apprtc.appspot.com). I have to stop the video track and have the audio track running such as the webcam is released from WebRTC and other app can use it. How do I do that?

I have started with things like:

```
pc.getLocalStreams()[0].getVideoTracks()[0].stop()
```

However, this does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do what you are asking for:

```
stream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled = false;
```

Comment: .enabled is more like "Mute" than drop the track/hardware, at least in Firefox and per the spec.

Comment: jesup is right, `enabled` is just a mute, it does not drop the hardware. And I don't want to stop the audio, I want to stop and drop the video.

Answer (score 0):

track.enabled is the right thing to use (for now) to "mute" the video; but it doesn't release the track/hardware.  Whether the hardware can be shared by applications is an OS issue.

Currently the only way to do so is to ask for a second stream of audio only (which implies a second request) or construct a new stream just from the audio track, and stop()/release the first stream, but there's no easy way to make that work in Firefox yet (until onnegotiationneeded is supported for re-invite-type operations, and MediaStream track-based constructors if you want to avoid the second permission request - note, Chrome's model for permissiona may hide this from you).

Comment: It is a huge OS issue I would say, when using WebRTC then trying to use the camera API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_the_Camera_API?redirect=no) makes the browser crash and even Android's camera app can't access the camera anymore, I have to restart the phone in order to get it back.